# C# the fastest way to send data sql or (TCPListener)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

Currently, I create a window application that will work on the principle of client communication with the server. And now I am thinking about the speed of communication. The question is: what will work faster:

1. Connecting both applications to the database and changing the values ​​in a given table, then downloading them with select?
2. Using TcpListener and connecting the application and communicating in this way?
   Will there be a very big difference in speed?
   It is about sending messages 1,2,3,4 and based on them, setting the values ​​of variables.

I wonder one more thing. If I want to connect applications using TcpListener, then I will not be able to use a global address and only work in LAN. Unless you set the DMZ on the server router.

Is there any other way to send such data? I would ask for examples.

Example of using TCPListener :

```
IPAddress ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(localhost).AddressList[0];
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ip, Convert.ToInt32(8080));
cpClient client = default(TcpClient);
```

Comment: From a design point of view, I would have the client communicate to the server application and only have the server talk to the database. Will that be slower? Well that depends where the server and database are located. If the database is on the same machine, then it won't be much slower than the client directly accessing the database. If the database is remote, then the server has to wait for the result from the database before returning anything to the client.

Comment: database is not for communication, pooling data in loop is terrible.

Comment: @JacekCz so what you recommended to use to communicate beetwen client -server using global ip address not inside lan - without cinfugre DMZ on client server

Comment: Without knowing more details about what you are trying to achieve it is very difficult to answer a question like this. How often will messages be sent, how critical is the lag between sending the message & setting values. There are many solutions to the problem as you have presented it - as well as writing your own code - it may be worth looking at existing frameworks like WCF.

Comment: Sending like 0,5 - 1 sec , dont accept lags :P

Comment: Well in the real world - communication does not happen instantaneously & CPUs run at a finite speed - so you are going to have to accept that there will be a lag.

Comment: @PaulF Don't scare to author. Simple transmision in LAN has very small lag (if programs are not broken under the mask - like database idea). @ Adam Use sockets :)

Comment: @JacekCz: properly constructed - there is no reason why a database system cannot run acceptably well - I have seen such systems running entire production factories. My comment regarding lag was a small joke - but there will always be a lag & without knowing what is an acceptable time of response or even what the application is - then as I said it is difficult to give sensible advice. For example - if multiple commands are sent & it is critical all are actioned even if there is a power outage - then the commands need storing by either the client or server - a database system maybe ideal then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use sockets is 2-3x faster than reading value from database. I testet both.